# Google forEach map.data feature not called

Tags: json, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to load a GeoJSON to the google maps javascript api and then process the GeoJSON by calling map.data.forEach . I cant get the map.data.forEach function to work it seems that it is never called.

The GeoJSON gets loaded fine and is displayed on my map.

Any suggestions why map.data.forEach would not work here?

Here is my code:

```js
var myMap;

function initialize() {
    // Create a simple map.
    myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        zoom: 8,
        center: {
            lat: 48.2081743,
            lng: 16.3738189
        }
    });

}

function calculate(map) {
    console.log("calculating")
    map.data.forEach(function (feature) {
        console.log("tester");
    });
    console.log("end calculating");
}

function loadGeoJson(map) {
    map.data.loadGeoJson('mini.json');
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
    initialize();
    loadGeoJson(myMap);
    calculate(myMap);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by javascripts asynchronous nature. When you have the code

```
loadGeoJson(myMap);
calculate(myMap);
```

and `loadGeoJson` loads an external resource, `calculate` will most likely be executed *before* `loadGeoJson` has finished. It is very easy to reproduce your problem.

Unfortunately there is no callback opportunity in [`google.maps.Data`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data)::`loadGeoJson`, but if you wrap the call of `calculate` into a small `setTimeout`, then you should be good :

```
loadGeoJson(myMap);
setTimeout(function() {
   calculate(myMap);
}, 500);
```

see a fiddle with your code from above -> **http://jsfiddle.net/SAS6Q/**

Comment: yes that solved the problem. I had something like this in my mind but I am fairly new to js so could not see wh this is not working, as you explained it now it looks quite clear. Thanks davidkonrad that really helped me a lot :)

Comment: According to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data there should now be a callback, however, it still wasn't working for me. Using your method worked fine for now :)

Comment: Thx for the comment, I tried it and the callback works fine. The timeout solution is pretty dodgy.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jQuery and Ajax to load your JSON synchronously to avoid setting time delays:

```
function loadGeoJson(map) {
  $.ajax({
    url: mini.json,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) 
              {var features = map.data.addGeoJson(data);}
    });
}
```